# Can't spot what is causing 'pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to transform a DataFrame that has information based on date and time as rows with multiple times within each day. The columns are date, time, open, high, low, close. This is what it looked like first:

```
date       | time     | open  | high | low | close

01-01-2020 | 09:30:00 |  1000 | 1001 | 999 | 999

01-01-2020 | 09:31:00 |  1000 | 1001 | 999 | 999
```

I have transformed it into a DataFrame which puts them all into one row based on the date:
da

```
date           | time                   | open         | high         | low       | close
    
    01-01-2020 | [09:30:00, 09:31:00]  |  [1000, 1000] | [1001, 1001] | [999,999] | [999,999]
```

I am now iterating through to turn that into this:

```
date       | 1 09:30:00 open | 1 09:31:00 open | 1 09:30:00 high | 1 09:31:00 high|   

01-01-2020 | 1000            | 1000            | 1001            | 1001           |
```

and so on...

This is my code:

```
df ['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df ['time']).dt.time
df = df.groupby('date').agg(list)

 one_min_df = pd.concat([
    pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([row[col]], index=[index],
                columns=[f'1 {h} {col}' for h in row['time']])
    for col in row.index[1:]], axis=1) 
    for index, row in df.iterrows()
    ])
```

I am getting the error:
'pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'
All of my columns are unique in the data frame I am using, so not really sure why this could be happening. This exact code worked on a different time frame (with 5 minute intervals).

Answer (score 0):

Your inner pd.concat() is iterating over index and row from the original df.iterrows(), which allows multiple values of the same index to propagate in the index=[index] declaration for your pd.DataFrame() call.

That's if the code references row[] as you intend. Your code does not execute in Python 3.9, partly because row[] isn't instantiated and also I think the arguments beginning with *for* need commas to separate them. The outer pd.concat() call is anticipating a list of dataframe objects.